# how to use a sum function in vba

Tags: vba, sum

I need to make  a function which calculates the formula:

```
Sigma(1/b^i)  i...n
```

It asks the user to fill in i and n

This is what I have so far:

```
b = InputBox("give your calue for b")
n = InputBox("give your value for n")

For i = 1 To n

answer = (1 / (b ^ i))


Next i


MsgBox ("" & answer)
```

At the moment it only give the last iteration. How do I add all the iterations together?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: try `answer = answer + (1 / (b ^ i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like

```
dim i, b, n, answer

b = InputBox("give your calue for b")
n = InputBox("give your value for n")

answer = 0 'initialization

For i = 1 To n

    answer = answer + (1 / (b ^ i))

Next

MsgBox (answer)
```